# How can I use/reference the selected value (TextBox) from a JavaScript Function into C# Code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

## aspx.cs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //ALPHA
        $('#COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX1').colorPicker({ pickerDefault: "E1E1E1", colors: ["E1E1E1", "33CC00", "FFF000", "CC0000", "996600", "FF9900", "303030", "0066FF", "F9A7B0", "9A0EEA"], transparency: true });
        $('#COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX2').colorPicker({ pickerDefault: "E1E1E1", colors: ["E1E1E1", "33CC00", "FFF000", "CC0000", "996600", "FF9900", "303030", "0066FF", "F9A7B0", "9A0EEA"], transparency: true });
    });
</script>

<asp:Table ID="Table" runat="server" style="border: medium solid #000000">
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell ID="TC2BC" HorizontalAlign="left" VerticalAlign="top">
            <asp:TextBox ID="COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX1" type="text" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell ID="TC9BC" HorizontalAlign="left" VerticalAlign="top" >
    <asp:TextBox ID="COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX2" type="text" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

I tried to use on the code behind cs:

```
COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX1.SelectedValue
```

But, I don't get that option in C#; What could be an alternative? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Is your code behind inheriting from `System.UI.Page` and you have correctly set the `codebehind` attribute on the aspx?

Comment: This code has mismatched tags, first `</asp:TableRow>` should be `<asp:TableRow>`

Comment: Why you use  SelectedValue for TextBox. May be you need to use COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX1.Text ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all fix ASPX markup, the first `</asp:TableRow>` should be `<asp:TableRow>` otherwise tags won't match.

Second, `TextBox` doesn't have`SelectedValue` property, it has `Text` propetrty.

And third - you cannot access inner nested control directly, you have to use FindControl to find it:

```
(TextBox)Table.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX1").Text
```

Comment: What I need is the selected value from the JavaScript in the TextBox, and not the TextBox property. So, how do I pass the JavaScript as a text?  Please, check the JavaScript.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. According to initial request you were trying to access control in code-behind C#

Comment: When the user clicks the TextBox, a palette of colors comes up, and then they select the color on a client-side(JS). So, what I need is that value of that color selected. Either get the JS to text or get the TextBox value selected, if that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

why are you trying to get the selected value of a textbox?  You should be using

```
  COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX1.Text
```

in the codebehind.

Also, don't use

```
Visible="false"
```

as this will cause the control to not be rendered.  if you want to hide a control (not sure why you would here, though) use:

```
 style="display:none"
```

Are you using another library with this control?  I don't see how you can be using a "color" picker without more code.  Are you using jQuery or the AjaxControlToolkit?

Comment: When the user clicks on the TextBox they get 5 options and it gets filled with the color selected. What I need is to reference the color selected on the TextBox from the JavaScript.

Comment: Please see appended response.

Comment: I'm using jQuery. The reason why I hide the control is because the user defines how many TextBoxes to load from a DropDownList. And, that code is generated behind.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is usually caused by one of two things:

- The .cs isn't inheriting from `System.UI.Page`
- The .aspx doesn't have the correct value in the `codebehind` attribute:

`<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="InheritSample.aspx.vb" Inherits="CodeBehindSamples.InheritSample"%>`

***however*** for a textbox `SelectedValue` is the *wrong* property, if you want its text you should be using `Text`:

```
COLOR_ALPHA_TEXTBOX1.Text
```